# Why does the array length function in Bash output a 1?

Tags: arrays, linux, bash, shell

i wonder why i get length 1 returned every time even though $test is empty, even though grep can't find anything.

```
#!/bin/bash

set -Eeuo pipefail
set -x

declare -a test

test=$(echo "$outputOfOtherCommand" | grep -i '>f\+\+\+\+\+\+\+\+\+' | cut -d' ' -f2) || true
echo "${#test[@]}"

for t in $test
do
    echo $t
done
```

The $outputOfOtherCommand includes the output of Rsync. The test_new_file was only created for clarity.

```
➜  ~ ./script.sh
.d..t...... ./
>f+++++++++ test_new_file

Number of files: 10 (reg: 9, dir: 1)
Number of created files: 1 (reg: 1)
Number of deleted files: 0
Number of regular files transferred: 1
Total file size: 0 bytes
Total transferred file size: 0 bytes
Literal data: 0 bytes
Matched data: 0 bytes
File list size: 0
File list generation time: 0.001 seconds
File list transfer time: 0.000 seconds
Total bytes sent: 280
Total bytes received: 38
```

The only thing I can explain is that an empty entry was created at array position 0. But i don't know. Maybe you can help me.

Comment: Your `for` loop does not make any sense. The loop body will be executed exactly once, with `t` having the literal string _test_.

Comment: Sorry, forgot the $ when I was making the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`test` is an array only because you declared it using `-a`. An assignment of the form

```
test=$(.....)
```

assigns a single string to `test`, which ends up in the array element with index 0. Hence the length of your array is 1.

You can verify this by

```
declare -a arr
arr=$(echo a b c)
echo ${arr[0]}
```

Comment: I see, then my question goes in a different direction. If I remove the "declare", I can go through the "array" with a for loop. Why is this possible when there is only an array with one element at position 0?

Comment: If you remove the 'declare', `test` is **not** an array anymore, but a string, but since you did not quote `$test` in your loop, word splitting occurs on white space and `t` will take the the values of the individual words. Whether this is or is not what you want, I don't know. You need to specify, what you want the array elements to contain.